# How to find the lp-name and ppa-name on launchpad to add with add-apt-repository?

Tags: command-line, ppa, package-info

My goal is to install the `libraw5` package. It is not a part of the standard Ubuntu packages already installed on my PC. I learned so far, that I have to search for this package on launchpad.net. There, I should find two important informations:

1. The name of the Launchpad-user
2. The PPA-name

Once I obtained these two informations I have to write into the shell:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:launchpad-user-name/ppa-name
```

I opened the site on launchpad.net and wrote the name of the package into the search bar. Unfortunately I can not find any hint for the launchpad-user-name and the ppa-name. Where to find them on this site?

Answer (score 1):

The package `libraw5` was for Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise).

For 14.04 (Trusty) you need

```
sudo apt-get install libraw9
```

for 15.04 (Vivid)

```
sudo apt-get install libraw10
```

---

And as you said in another comment, to install `lightzone` use the PPA ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/lightzone

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/lightzone
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightzone
```